# Simple full-duplex communication between P2P

Tags: python, sockets, networking, p2p

I intend to set up a master process and many peerProcess connect to the master process (for lab in school ) . Then the master process will collect the port and address of it connected (client) peers into a list and send its back to the peerProcess. (I run the peer process on the same terminal on my laptop so it may have the same address, I guess)

I want to ask if there are any problems with my understanding with full-duplex communication set up

And how should I change to have the communication work?

This is peerServer.py - for peers

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import random
import time

# Use the current time as a seed for the random number generator
random.seed(time.time())

# Generate a random integer
random_number = random.randint(15001, 15500)
peer_port = random_number

def master_bigboss():
    master_host = socket.gethostname()
    master_port = 5000
    peer_socket = socket.socket()
    peer_socket.connect((master_host, master_port))
    message = "add info"
    peer_socket.send(message.encode())
    time.sleep(3)
    message = str(peer_port)
    peer_socket.send(message.encode())
    peer_socket.close()

def do_work():
    master_host = socket.gethostname()
    master_port = 5000
    peer_socket = socket.socket()
    peer_socket.connect((master_host, master_port))
    message = "get list"
    peer_socket.send(message.encode())
    data = peer_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    received_list = data.split(",")
    print("List of Peers:", received_list)
    peer_socket.close()

def accept_connection(conn, addr):
    # Handle the connection, e.g., receive and send messages
    print(f"Peer connected: {addr}")

def register_port(peer_port):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(('', peer_port))
    server.listen(5)
    print(f"PeerServer starts on port {peer_port}\n")

    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"Connection from: {addr}\n")
        peer_conn = Thread(target=accept_connection, args=(conn, addr))
        peer_conn.start()


# Function to handle receiving messages from a peer
def receive_messages(peer_socket):
    print("start receiving!")
    while True:
        try:
            message = peer_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            if message:
                print(f"Received message: {message}")
            else:
                break
        except ConnectionResetError:
            break

# Function to communicate with a selected peer
def communicate_with_peer(peer_ip, peer_port):
    peer_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    peer_socket.connect((peer_ip, peer_port))

    # Start a thread to receive messages from the peer
    receive_thread = Thread(target=receive_messages, args=(peer_socket,))
    receive_thread.start()

    while True:
        message = input("Enter your message (Type 'exit' to end): ")
        if message.lower() == 'exit':
            break
        peer_socket.send(message.encode())

    # Close the connection
    peer_socket.close()

# Function to handle sending messages to a peer
def send_messages(peer_socket):
    while True:
        message = input("Enter your message (Type 'exit' to end): ")
        peer_socket.send(message.encode())
        if message.lower() == 'exit':
            break

# Function to initiate full-duplex communication with a selected peer
def full_duplex_communication(peer_ip, peer_port):
    peer_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    peer_socket.connect((peer_ip, peer_port))

    
        # Start a thread to send messages to the peer
    send_thread = Thread(target=send_messages, args=(peer_socket,))
    send_thread.start()
   
        # Start a thread to receive messages from the peer
    receive_thread = Thread(target=receive_messages, args=(peer_socket,))
    receive_thread.start()

    receive_thread.join()
    send_thread.join()

    # Close the connection after both sending and receiving threads finish
    peer_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    binder = Thread(target=register_port, args=(peer_port,))
    binder.start()

    mstconnect = Thread(target=master_bigboss)
    print("Calling master_bigboss to register info")
    mstconnect.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    opt = Thread(target=do_work)
    print("Calling do_work to get the list of peers")
    opt.start()
    time.sleep(3)

    while(1):
        option = input("What do you want: \n")
        if(option == '1'):
            opt = Thread(target=do_work)
            print("Getting the list of peers...")
            opt.start()
        elif(option == '0'):
            break;
        elif(option =='2'):
            print("Ready to setup connect ...\n")
            peerPort = input("Choose the Peer port from peerList to connect! \n")
            # print(socket.gethostbyname() + " in port " + peerPort);
            # opt=Thread(target=communicate_with_peer, arg=('10.230.164.114',int(peerPort)));
            # opt.start()
            full_duplex_communication('10.230.164.114' ,int(peerPort));
        else:
            print("can not be done.")


   

    # Wait for threads to finish
    binder.join()
    mstconnect.join()
    opt.join()
```

And this is Master.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread, Lock

PeerList = []
lock = Lock()

def addInfo(peerPort):
    with lock:
        PeerList.append(peerPort)

def accept_connection(connection, address):
    print("Connected by", address)
    
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(1024).decode()
        print(str(data))
        if data.lower().strip() == 'add info':
            print("Master is adding info:") 
            peerPort = connection.recv(1024).decode()
            print(peerPort)
            addInfo(peerPort)
            print("List of Peers:", PeerList)
            
        elif data.lower().strip() == 'get list':
            print("Master is sending the list of Peers")
            peer_list_str = ",".join(map(str, PeerList))
            connection.sendall(peer_list_str.encode())
            break
        else:
            return

def register_port(host, port=5000):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((host, port))
    print(f"Master starts - host: {host} : port {port}\n")
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"Connection from: {addr}\n")
        Peer_conn = Thread(target=accept_connection, args=(conn, addr))
        Peer_conn.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000
    binder = Thread(target=register_port, args=(host, port))
    binder.start()
    
    # Wait for the binder thread to finish
    binder.join()
```

When the peerProcess know others port and address, it can connect and communicate. But the problem is that the commucation can only send, can not receive. (I might have changed something in hope that it will work but now it can not set up the connection between the peers)

Comment: The first problem is TCP is not message-based.  It is a byte stream.  **You** have to send a byte stream that can be parsed to determine start/end of messages, e.g. "each message ends in \n" or "4-byte little-endian size header followed by 'size' bytes of message".  One send != a recv of the same size.  Then buffer recv and extract complete messages.